# How can I use JMX to access the threads of a remote JVM?

Tags: java, jmx

How can I use JMX to access the threads of a remote JVM?

Comment: simplest: java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean()

Comment: With java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean() where do I specify the remote host name?

Comment: `remote` is new :). Maybe a link this time: http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/jmx.html

Comment: I tried that link, but it doesn't give the JMXServiceURL URI for the PlatformMBeanServer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very old thread, but since I was looking and found the actual answer to this question I may as well post it.

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Development-Class/ThisFullThreadDumpclassdemonstratesthecapabilitytogetafullthreaddumpandalsodetectdeadlockremotely.htm

The above shows a very nice example on how to get access to all threads on a remote JMX.

In Synopsis:

```
// First connect to the remote service
String urlPath = "/jndi/rmi://" + hostname + ":" + port + "/jmxrmi";
JMXServiceURL url = new JMXServiceURL("rmi", "", 0, urlPath);
JMXConnector jmxc = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(url);
MBeanServerConnection server = jmxc.getMBeanServerConnection();

// Then get all threads
ThreadMXBean tmbean = newPlatformMXBeanProxy(server, THREAD_MXBEAN_NAME, ThreadMXBean.class);
ObjectName tmbean = new ObjectName(THREAD_MXBEAN_NAME);
long[] tids = tmbean.getAllThreadIds();
ThreadInfo[] tinfos = tmbean.getThreadInfo(tids, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
for (ThreadInfo ti : tinfos) {
  // do something with this particular thread...
}
```

To emphasize the possible need to want to write your own monitoring tool as questioned by @aaron-mciver; threads contain a lot of information and in a business process there can be a lot of threads and it may not be possible to look through them by eye-balling them in VisualVM for instance.
It can make a lot of sense to programmatically loop through the threads to look for specific keywords, CPU times, stack traces, filenames involved etc...

Comment: Why the down-vote? The answer is exactly what is asked :(

Answer (score 1):

Why not use [jvisualvm](https://visualvm.dev.java.net/) as it comes as part of the SDK and will give you access to the threads within a given JVM amongst other things.

No point in attempting to replicate debugging features which already exist.

Comment: how do you run visualVM in a headless environment?

Comment: You can remotely monitor an application with jvisualvm...not sure what specifics you are looking for or if this was a loaded question and something awaits...my point was that if you can leverage what jvisualvm or jconsole provide then do it; don't create JMX hooks to propagate information already readily available.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that. How can I call VisualVM from my Java code to get this information?

Comment: Zubair...you would have jvisualvm monitor your application (JVM); not your application calling jvisualvm. http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/applications_window.html